# At what concentration is sodium bicarbonate a sanitizing solution?

Tags: food-safety, cleaning

I can't find an authoritative answer to the question @rumtscho asked me [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/33347/641) about the concentration of sodium bicarbonate, mixtures of which I've come to rely on as a cleaning and sanitizing solution for refrigerators.

I've seen just about any combination you can think of:

```
With just enough water to form a paste.
With water and vinegar.
With lots of water.
5% dilution in water.
0.5% dilution in water.
```

Most 'recipes' are not very exact. I've also read that it can be harmful, so the issue is not without interest. Especially as I've been cleaning my fridge with the 5% dilution.

Others, on the Internet, claim that it's a harmless substance and recommend it against stomach pains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sodium bicarbonate alone is not a *sanitizer* at any concentration, although it may be an effective *cleaner*, mostly due to its abrasive quality.  It may be used in certain sanitization regimes, in combination with other chemicals and agents.

[Food Safety Site](http://www.foodsafetysite.com/educators/competencies/foodservice/cleaning/cas1.html) of Clemson University does not list it as a sanitizing agent.  According to [21 CFR 178.1010 - Sanitizing solutions](http://cfr.vlex.com/vid/178-1010-sanitizing-solutions-19706617) (as queried through VLex), it is a part of two sanitizing regimes, but not the only component.

There are many non-credible, non-scientific sites that seem to claim sodium bicarbonate has anti-fungal properties, but I do not consider them worthy of consideration.

In terms of reputable sources, there is some evidence [from NIH](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18396809) that sodium bicarbonate, at concentrations of 3%, can contribute to anti-fungal properties (at least for storing oranges), but it is part of an overall plan also including biological antagonists, not used alone.

I would not take this to mean that sodium bicarbonate is a sanitizing agent, which is a much stronger statement than simply reducing growth of fungus, which is only one possible type of pathogen.  I simply cannot find any evidence to support this stronger statement.

Comment: Na(HCO3), sodium bicarbonate is alkaline or acts as a base in water: HCO3- + H2O → H2CO3 + OH−
The bicarbonate ion takes an hydrogen from water and results in a hydroxide, this raises the pH, and a high pH is poor for fungal growth and can prevent sporulation (sort of like germination for plants), http://books.google.com/books?id=tpnBqSZzw0kC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=ph+fungal+sporulation&source=bl&ots=Tf4E08v4Rk&sig=UKdSKoppfqRmFTuNdCjJh4TF7rY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fwuUUd6ZOIfO8QSH5oG4Bg&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=ph%20fungal%20sporulation&f=false.